# Replace the block behind a sign

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

Recently I started working on a new plugin and I'm having problems finding how can I replace the block a sign is attached to.. I tried a few methods from the internet none was working
Any ideas for how can I do such a thing?  ( I have the object "type :Sign name: sign"witch is the sign I want to replace the block behind him)

Thank you very much for reading

FIXED EDIT:
Somewhere inside main method :

```
e.getPlayer().sendMessage("DETECTED");
                Block sb = sign.getBlock();// "sign " is type Sign imported from org.bukkit.block.Sign
            Block b =  RedstoneSign.getblock(sb);
            b.setType(Material.REDSTONE_BLOCK);
```

main method imports:

```
    import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.block.Sign;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
```

getblock method:

```
public static Block getblock (Block b){

    if (b.getType() == Material.WALL_SIGN || b.getType() == Material.SIGN_POST)
    { 
        Sign s = (Sign) b.getState().getData();//in this case "s" is type "Sign" imported from org.bukkit.material.Sign
        return b.getRelative(s.getAttachedFace());
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

getblock imports:

```
 import org.bukkit.Material;
    import org.bukkit.block.Block;
    import org.bukkit.material.Sign;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Sign s = (Sign) block.getState().getData();
 Block attachedBlock = b.getRelative(s.getAttachedFace());
 attachedBlock.setType(Material.DIRT);
```

The import must be `org.bukkit.material.Sign` NOT `org.bukkit.block.Sign`

Comment: Yes the org.bukkit.material.Sign  was my mistake I tried to import from both org.bukkit.material.Sign and org.bukkit.block.Sign that failed and I just moved the method to another package (I need org.bukkit.Sign for my method ) now it's working thanks you

Comment: @toto: If you need both imported, import the one you need more of (probably `org.bukkit.block.Sign`) and then manually use the fully-qualified version here: `org.bukkit.material.Sign s = (org.bukkit.material.Sign) block.getState().getData();`